# Strange output of php decorator pattern

Tags: php, polymorphism, decorator

I have implemented a basic snipe of code based in decorator pattern.

Decorator class:

```
abstract class HTMLDecorator {

    /** @var \ArrayObject */
    protected $notes;

    public function format(){
        $html = '';

        foreach ($this->getNodes() as $node)
            $html .= "<p>{$node}</p>";

        return $html;
    }
}
```

This is the base class:

```
class HTML extends HTMLDecorator{

    public function __construct(){
        $this->nodes = new \ArrayObject();
    }

    public function getNodes(){
        return $this->nodes;
    }
}
```

Now, these two classes add nodes to the html array.

Block:

```
class BlockHtml extends HTMLDecorator{

    protected $html;

    public function __construct(HTMLDecorator $html){
        $this->html = $html;
    }

    public function getNodes()
    {
        $this->html->getNodes()->append('Block html');
        return $this->html->getNodes();
    }

}
```

Image:

```
class ImageHtml extends HTMLDecorator{

    protected $html;

    public function __construct(HTMLDecorator $html){
        $this->html = $html;
    }

    public function getNodes()
    {
        $this->html->getNodes()->append('Image html');
        return $this->html->getNodes();
    }

}
```

Finally, I have tested it as doing:

```
$html = new HTML()
$html = BlockHTML($html);
$html = ImageHTML($html);
echo $html->format();
```

The result is:

```
Block html
Image html
Block html
```

Why does code print "Block html" twice?

Comment: `$html = ImageHTML($thml);` typo ?

Comment: Typo fixed, thank you

Comment: Calling $html = ImageHTML($html); using the result obtained from $html = BlockHTML($html);might causing the problem. Can you try to assign the returned value to different variable and assemble it at the end.

Comment: @FrozenFire, your words had sence, because calling `getNodes()` inside of the another `getNotes()`'s class filled my array twice. And yes, declaring another variable fix the problem! Could you please post your comment as an answer?

Comment: Ok, I have posted the answer here.

Comment: use a debugger and you'll see ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl, I do know how use a debugger in php. This will be my next assignment.

Comment: @manix Are you using an IDE like eclipse or netbeans?

Comment: @hek2mgl No, I am using phpStorm (jetbrains) in a localhost enviroment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$html = ImageHTML($html);` using the result obtained from `$html = BlockHTML($html);` might causing the problem. Can you try to assign the returned value to different variable and assemble it at the end.